# Access parsed json key using a variable in Logic App

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

Can we access parsed JSON key using logic app variable?

I have a string type variable with value as FY23-01 like below:

[image]

And a parsed JSON like below:

```
{
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "FY23-01": "1",
  "FY23-02": "2",
  "FY23-03": "3",
  "FY23-04": "4",
}
```

Now I want to get the value of key "FY23-01". I am using below expression and it always returns blank:

```
body('Parse_JSON')?[variables('secondContent')]
```

Is it supported to use variables in key reference for JSON?

Comment: It should work, it works for me.  Can you show us your flow so we can try and replicate the issue exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is  supported to use variables in key reference for JSON.

The expression
`body('Parse_JSON')?[variables('secondContent')]` should work to access the value from Json.

One of the alternative approach is using this expression `outputs('Parse_Json')?['body']?[variables('secondContent')]`. I have tried in both the ways and below are steps I followed,

- Created logic app shown below,
  [image]
- From http trigger sending below json and using parse json action to parse json received from http request trigger.
  [image]
  [image]
- Initialized variable as shown below,
  [image]
- Initialized another variable to store value of json key with the expression  `outputs('Parse_Json')?['body']?[variables('secondContent')]`,
  [image]
- Logic app ran successfully and output is,
  [image]
- One of the other approach is selecting key from directly parse json as shown,

[image]

- I have used expression `body('Parse_JSON')?[variables('secondContent')]`, this also worked and got result.
  [image]
  output:
  [image]

Comment: Thanks @vijaya. Yes its working once I hard coded the values. Not sure why in my variable the value is coming as 'FY23-01\n\n' which is causing blank response.